# Getting error: Wrong top statement declaration in Scala

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

Boundary.scala and World.scala are both giving me wrong top statement declaration error in Scala. What can I do to fix this?

Boundary.scala

```
package physics

class ​Boundary(​var ​start: PhysicsVector, ​var ​end: PhysicsVector){

}
```

World.scala

```
package ​physics

class ​World(​var ​gravity: Double) {​
var ​objects​: ​List​[PhysicalObject] = ​List​()​
var ​boundaries​: ​List​[Boundary] = ​List​()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of zero-width-space (`\u200b`) characters in your code, see what's there when replacing `\u200b` with `\u26A0` (warn sign):

```
class ⚠World(⚠var ⚠gravity: Double) {⚠
var ⚠objects⚠: ⚠List⚠[PhysicalObject] = ⚠List⚠()⚠
var ⚠boundaries⚠: ⚠List⚠[Boundary] = ⚠List⚠()
}
```

Just remove them or replace with regular spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the help. By the way, is this only an issue with the language Scala?

Comment: @Anonymous no, most languages don't allow you to sprinkle zero-width spaces throughout your code. As for why the spaces are there, who can say? It might be your editor, or maybe you copied the code from somewhere that had them.

Comment: @Anonymous: You will have to read the language specification of the language you want to know about, to find out whether it allows zero-width-space and how it treats zero-width-space. The vast majority of languages still have a very ASCII-centric view of the world and only allow space, tab, carriage return, and linefeed as whitespace. And in many languages, carriage return and linefeed are "special" whitespace that also serves as statement terminator.